# I can not scrape Google news with Beautiful soup. I am getting the error:TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been working on some web scraping exercise for some time now and it seems to have been going well, till I encountered Google news. I am using Beautiful soup to scrape these sites, but each time I try to scrape google news, I get the error`TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` even though I am fairly confident I am using the right tags.

After a lot of attempts, I decided to print out the source code of the page in my text editor (the one that beautiful soup is receiving) and I discovered that it doesn't contain any tag(which might explain why I am getting that error)

here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

page_info=urlopen('https://news.google.com')
soup=BeautifulSoup(page_info,'html.parser')
headlines=soup.findall('div',{'jscontroller':'d0DtYd'})
for head in headlines:
    headline=head.find('h3').find('a').get_text()
    print(headline)
```

is there a particular reason, I am having this problem, or is there something crucial I am missing. I need some help.

Comment: Web scraping is against Google's terms of service.

Comment: That error message is well-documented.  Please look it up.  Then insert one or two `print` commands to display your results up to the point of failure.  Explain where you're confused about those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website is loaded dynamically using javascript, so you can't use `requests` or `urllib` to scrape it. The best way is to use `selenium`. Apart from that, your `find_all` statement was wrong. It should be `find_all`, not `findall`.

Thus, Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('https://news.google.com')

time.sleep(4)

page_info = driver.page_source

driver.close()

soup=BeautifulSoup(page_info,'html5lib')
headlines=soup.find_all('div',{'jscontroller':'d0DtYd'})
for head in headlines:
    headline=head.find('h3').find('a').get_text()
    print(headline)
```

Output:

```
US presidential debate LIVE: Trump making friends with ‘thugs’ like Putin and Kim, says Biden
To buy or not to buy: Why BJP’s Bihar move comes as a surprise to states
Two terrorists surrender after families brought to encounter site in Jammu and Kashmir`s Baramulla
Fire breaks out at City Centre mall in Mumbai
After teacher’s killing, French Muslims fear rising Islamophobia
To buy or not to buy: Why BJP’s Bihar move comes as a surprise to states
Delhi's air quality dips, morning walkers irked
55,839 Fresh Coronavirus Cases In India, Total Cases At 77.06 Lakh: 10 Points
After Bihar, Tamil Nadu, Madhya Pradesh Promise Free Vaccine: 10 Points
US presidential debate LIVE: Trump making friends with ‘thugs’ like Putin and Kim, says Biden
COVID-19 vaccine may be ready by December. Trials to safety — a look at India's vaccine journey
US Elections 2020 HIGHLIGHTS: Intelligence agencies say Iran, Russia have tried to meddle in polls
Trump-allied groups pour $30 million into Barrett’s confirmation to Supreme Court
```

**NOTE: The output might be different for you because we both live in different parts of the world.**

Comment: THANKS!!! I discovered that that problem had always been the "findall()" I was using. As soon as I changed it to  "find_all()", it worked out quit well. Though when I tried to use the request library, it didn't work and returned the error [TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()]. Thanks once again.